# The requested container identifier is not permitted by the client's com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, xcode6, icloud

I am facing a few issues and I would think I'm not the only one.

I have an App in the App Store that uses `Core Data` and `iCloud` to save user added information across user's devices. There's nothing fancy about that and it works really well. It's an iOS 7 app and it works very well on iOS 8 as well. When I test it on a device with iOS 8. It works very well with Xcode 5.1.1 but it doesn't with Xcode 6.0.1.

It seems like Apple have changed a few things with iCloud in iOS 8. Session 225: "What's new in Core Data" https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ seems to say nothing much has changed.

**Problem**

In the Developer Portal, it looked like I had to create new iCloud Containers. (I have no idea what that is or how to get rid of it). It creates this with "iCloud.bundleID" - i.e., the word iCloud at the front.

Before Xcode 6, my entitlements were:

"xxxxxxxx.com.vital.lope" where xxxxxxx is my TeamID.

Now, in the capabilities pane, there's no iCloud Core Data option (but according to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW28 under the Choose the Proper Storage API, iCloud Documents is used for Core Data as well). That's fine.

I've selected to use Custom Containers:

[image]

The reason? Well because in my code now, in the App Delegate, I have:

```
// Returns the URL to our Ubiquity Folder
- (NSURL *)grabCloudPath:(NSString *)filename {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *teamID = @"xxxxxxxxx"; // replace with your real Team ID
    NSString *bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundleIdentifier];
    NSString *cloudRoot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", teamID, bundleID];

    NSURL *cloudRootURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:cloudRoot];

    NSString *pathToCloudFile = [[cloudRootURL path]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    pathToCloudFile = [pathToCloudFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToCloudFile];
}
```

Which is called from the persistentStoreCoorindator. Again, this works well before Xcode 6.

If I run my app in Xcode 6.0.1, the user is presented with an option to turn iCloud On. If they do, the app crashes with the following error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (LibrarianErrorDomain error 11 - The requested container identifier is not permitted by the client's com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement.)" 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

If I run an exception breakpoint, it crashes at the return statement in the `grabCloudPath` code above.

In that method, if I change

```
NSString *cloudRoot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", teamID, bundleID];
```

to

```
NSString *cloudRoot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iCloud.%@.%@", teamID, bundleID];
```

The app does not crash anymore, but then no iCloud data comes in because it's now a different folder.

Back in the Capabilities Pane, I have:

[image]

This shows there are no errors, but this also occurred automatically without me doing anything.

**Things I have learnt**

After watching the session 225 of WWDC 2014, I can see that I'm supposed to use iCloud Core Data still and there should be no changes. However, that option doesn't exist within the Capabilities pane.

[image]

I know I'm not using CloudKit, or supposed to use CloudKit for my application because it's not the same requirement. I learnt that after also watching the CloudKit session in the WWDC videos.

**Questions**

The main questions are:

1) Do I need iCloud containers?
2) Why can I not just carry on using the same container that I created with my app?
3) IF I need to use iCloud containers, how do I transfer the data from the existing container (xxxxxxx.com.vital.lope) to the new iCloud container (iCloud.xxxxxxx.com.vital.lope). 
4) Do I use the CloudKit support or support for Xcode 5 in the Developer Portal for iCloud?

[image]

**Update**

I went back to the Developer Portal, removed the Cloud containers for my App ID and selected to use the Xcode 5. When I re-added my provisioning profiles, my app crashed at the same place. If I changed to use the default container in the Capabilities pane, my app crashed in the same place.

I hope this question makes sense and I cannot imagine I'm the only one facing this issue, but I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Dear @tom144g - I think I may have resolved this issue, but it was by no means easy. I raised an Apple Support Ticket and they explained to me that all iCloud directories had been ported over to iCloud.containeridentifier.com and that affected some apps in the process. I had to request for them to reinstate my original identifier for iCloud, which had to be done through the Developer Portal. Now in the Developer Portal, under containers, I have my original iCloud container identifier. I hope this makes sense, but I'm happy to discuss further what issues you may be facing.